# [expr.unary.op]/9 seems to imply that the `operator !()` could not be applied to the type A below. But compilers disagree with that

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, unary-operator

[[conv]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv#4):

> Certain language constructs require that an expression be converted to
>   a Boolean value. An expression `e` appearing in such a context is said
>   to be *contextually converted to `bool`* and is well-formed if and
>   only if the declaration `bool t(e);` is well-formed, for some invented
>   temporary variable `t` (11.6).

Consider now the snippet below. It doesn't compile, neither in [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/866ba3623fba4dc8), [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/049a411350ef8cd6) or [VS](http://rextester.com/WMHEMU15817).

```
struct A{ bool operator!() { return true; } };
int main(){
    A a;
    bool t(a);
}
```

Thus, from [conv]/4 we conclude that the type `A` is **not** contextually converted to `bool`.

[[expr.unary.op]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#9):

> The operand of the logical negation operator `!` is contextually
>   converted to `bool` (Clause 7); its value is `true` if the converted
>   operand is `false` and `false` otherwise. The type of the result is
>   `bool`.

My understanding of the paragraph above is that the operand of the logical negation operator `!` must be contextually converted to `bool`. We have just concluded that the type `A` is **not** contextually converted to `bool`. Therefore, from [expr.unary.op]/9, we can say that the following code should **not** compile. But it does, in [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ea19016164fa08b), [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8900f6d1a76aac88) and [VS](http://rextester.com/YUX54013).

```
struct A{ bool operator!() { return true; } };
int main(){
    A a;
    bool t = !a;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: That is not a logical negation operator, its the member function `A::operator!`, is my guess anyways. I believe this is the same thing with `operator,`, the comma operator has an inherent meaning even without an overload, but is well defined when provided with an overload

Comment: Try changing `bool t(a);` to `bool t(!a);` in your 1st example.  As in how can the compiler guess it needs to apply `operator!`.

Comment: [Clause \[expr\] defines the effects of operators when applied to types for which they have not been overloaded.](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#3.sentence-1)

Comment: @Rakete1111 It does in C++1z

Comment: @PasserBy What, really. Good to know, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Wait, I'm doubing myself now, can't find it in the standard. Forgot where I got the information from in the first place

Comment: @PasserBy Jup, I can't find it either. [It looks like you're wrong](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cfec95397b2c2f3). You'll have to check out your source :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[[expr]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#3.sentence-1) as a whole applies to built-in operators:

> Clause [expr] defines the effects of operators when applied to types for which they have not been overloaded.

The definition in [expr.unary.op] is simply the definition of the *built-in* `operator!`. Additionally, [[over.match.oper]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#3) describes how to look up overloaded operators:

> For a unary operator @ with an operand of a type whose cv-unqualified version is T1, [...], three sets of candidate functions, designated member candidates, non-member candidates and built-in candidates, are constructed as follows: [...]

For `!a`, you'd have two candidates: your overload `A::operator!()` and the built-in defined in [[over.built]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.built#24):

> There also exist candidate operator functions of the form
>
> ```
> bool operator!(bool);
> ```

For the built-in to be selected by overload resolution, the type would have to be contextually converted to `bool`<sup>†</sup> as your argument suggests. However, this candidate is not viable - but the overloaded member operator is.

---

<sup>†</sup>[T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44679200/expr-unary-op-9-seems-to-imply-that-the-operator-could-not-be-applied-to/44679576?noredirect=1#comment76347693_44679576) is on top of it as usual, pointing out [cwg issue 1919](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1919) which indicates that a type that *is* contextually convertible to `bool` still shouldn't use the builtin `operator!` due to a wording issue. Although, both gcc and clang permit it (which is what we all want to happen, probably).

Comment: @T.C. You never cease to amaze. Also Johannes has apparently submitted every core issue.